Reuse of same coroutine (asyncio)
I am not sure why I am getting cannot reuse already awaited coroutine in my code.
I am calling this code in a for loop twice
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
if loop.is_running():
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.async_print_stats(curb, iswhite, full))
else:
    loop.run_until_complete(self.async_print_stats(curb, iswhite, full))

It takes the same else branch twice. It works the first time, and in the sec time, I get the runtime error on the only line of this function:
async def async_print_stats(self, fen, iswhite, full=True):
    print(await self.async_ret_stats(fen, iswhite, full))
          ^

I just don't see how I am waiting on the same coroutine simulatiounsly( like in gather here:
Can I await the same Task multiple times in Python? )
, so I don't understand the reason for the error.
I tried creating a task, but it argues the loop isn't running.
UPDATE:
import asyncio 
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def tmp():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('a')
async def func():
    await tmp()
    print('b')

for i in range(2):
    loop.run_until_complete(func())

This code works. But I haven't done anything else really.
So at this point I am not sure what could have caused it.

Well, what's async_ret_stats? Can you post a [mcve]?

I will post. I just don't see how it can  be related to the implementation of the function. there is no any kind of recursion I left out (i.e. async_ret doesnt call async_print). It also doesnt use asyncio  module.

please do not put code in comments, especially python, as it loses all formatting, and we all know how important formatting is in python

So it is not that interesting , as apperently the error is unrlated.
I mistakenly did caching of arguments in this case, and the cache would only work for def functions.
That is why the second time I called it, the flow was different.
